# Maximum distance achieved by a rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry

Imagine $N$ points $p_1,\cdots,p_N$ in the plane. Assume also that 
$$\|p_i-p_j\|\geq r\quad \forall j\neq i$$
for some $r>0$. Consider now a rotation of the axis i.e.
$$\bar{p_i}=R\:p_i$$
for some rotation matrix
$$R:=\left[\matrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) &  \cos(\theta)}\right]$$
I wonder if we can find an angle $\theta$   such that the minimum distance between the resulting $\bar{x}$ (or $\bar{y}$) coordinates be maximum. Specifically I am interested in
$$\max_{\theta}\min_{\substack{i, j\\i\neq j}}|\bar{x}_i-\bar{x}_j|$$
with $\bar{x}_i$, $\bar{y}_i$ the coordinates of the $i$-th point in the new system i.e.  $\bar{p}_i:=(\bar{x}_i,\bar{y}_i)$.

**Edit:** I am not necessarily looking for a sharp optimal value. If we can prove that there exists some $\theta$ such that $$\min_{\substack{i, j\\i\neq j}}|\bar{x}_i-\bar{x}_j|\geq \delta(N,r) r$$ 
for some $\delta(N,r)\in(0,1)$ this would be a nice step.

Comment: If you consider one pair of points you can draw the line through them.  If you rotate the coordinates so one axis is perpendicular to the line, the coordinates of the points along the other axis will be the same.  Each pair of points gives a direction to avoid

Comment: @RossMillikan Thank you for your comment. I understand this but as the number of points increase the resulting minimum distances seem (geometrically) to decrease. I am analyzing an algorithm and need this lower bound for my proof.

Comment: Yes, if you have 100 points you will have $\frac 12(100)(99)$ directions all of which yield a zero minimum distance because there are that many pairs of points.  There won't be much room between them so the minimum distance seems like it should be small.

Comment: @RossMillikan Exactly, but you can always find some line which is not parallel to anyone of these, so that all points have different projections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let us consider one pair of points.  We can rotate the coordinates so the $x$ axis is perpendicular to the line between them.  The two points will then be $(x,a)$ and $(x,b)$ and the minimum coordinate distance is zero.  As we rotate the coordinates they are at $(x\cos \theta - b \sin \theta, x \sin \theta+b \cos \theta)$ and $(x\cos \theta - a \sin \theta, x \sin \theta+a \cos \theta)$ with minimum distance $\min((a-b) \sin \theta, (a-b) \cos \theta)$  We will care about small angles, so the minimum distance will be $(a-b)\sin \theta$.  You have said that $a-b \ge r$

You have $\frac 12N(N-1)$ pairs of points.  Each pair will define four directions for the $+x$ axis where the minimum distance is zero.  Intuitively, you want to rotate the coordinates so your axes are as far from these directions as possible.  You can imagine plotting the $2N(N-1)$ directions for the $+x$ axis around the circle.  There must be a gap of at least $\frac {\pi}{N(N-1)}$ radians between two neighboring points.  The centerline of that gap will have a minimum difference of $r \sin \left(\frac {\pi}{2N(N-1)}\right)$.  You can do somewhat better if the distance between the points on one side is greater than $r$ by moving $\theta$ in that direction or by choosing a smaller gap where the point spacings for the lines on each side is larger, but this is a lower bound.

Comment: Great answer!! Thank you!

Comment: Do you think that the argument can be generalized for the case of $m>2$ dimensions?

Comment: Yes, I think so but there are subtleties I have not figured out.  In 3D, the direction of one axis does not fix the other two, unlike 2D.  I imagine triangulating the sphere using these points.  Then you can put one axis though the largest triangle but need to choose the other two far from the disallowed directions as well.

Comment: The best I can see in 3D is to consider you have $\frac 12N(N-1)$ points on the sphere that you can't point the $+x$ axis.  You can make a [Voroni diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)  on the sphere and draw the largest circle around each point that fits into its Voroni cell.  You want to point your axes outside all these circles.  Finding three allowable orthogonal directions may be difficult.

Comment: Thank you. My thoughts: each of the $r=N(N-1)/2$  points on the sphere defines a great circle (GC) with all the directions to be avoided. These GCs intersect on the sphere surface and define (convex ?)  polygons which are at most $r^2-r+2$ (a new GC  can add at most 2*(number of existing GC) regions). These polygons are the directions to be avoided and since they cover the whole space there exist at least one with area $4\pi/(r^2-r+2)$. Selecting the center of the largest one will do the job but I cannot see a way to find the max distance of the center from the edges which defines the bound.

Comment: I have created a new question on the subject if you want to contribute ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226061/vector-placement-for-optimal-projections/2226081?noredirect=1#comment4577207_2226081 )